# SNMP performance changes when querying from a different computer

Tags: performance, snmp, net-snmp

I am working on an auditing project that of course involves [SNMP](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/). While querying different devices I have noticed huge performance difference when querying a machine from two different computers. Let's make an example. When I query my Cisco 2960G switch from Debian *snmpwalk* is REALLY slow, by slow I mean that each *get* takes few seconds before complete. With SUSE Enterprise instead *snmpwalk* is fast as usual and *get* operations are almost instant. Debian is running NET-SNMP 5.4.3 while SUSE is running NET-SNMP 5.4.2.1. Notice that this performance discrepancy happens only with certain devices such as Cisco switches and some printers (Lexmark usually). What's the reason of this huge gap?

EDIT: I just updated NET-SNMP on Debian to version [5.7.2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/net-snmp/files/net-snmp/5.7.2-pre-releases/) but performance are as slow as before.

Comment: What values do `avgBusy1` (1.3.6.1.4.1.9.2.1.57.0) and  `busyPer` (1.3.6.1.4.1.9.2.1.56.0) return when you poll the Cisco switch (while it is slow)?

Comment: So, from SUSE (the fast one) they both return 5 or 6 always. On Debian (the slow one) they go from 4 to 5 to 6. It is quite random though. And ofcourse this snmpget takes few seconds on Debian while it is instant on SUSE. Just a note regarding your question since you said "while it is slow". It's not a period, it is always slow.

Comment: Have you run `tcpdump` or similar to see if it is the machine or the switch that is acting slow?  IE, if on debian you run snmpget and the packet goes out immediately then you likely know the problem is related to the switch.  Also, run snmpget with the `-d` switch to see what packets it is sending out, and optionally the verbose version: `-Ddump`

Comment: It is quite hard to dump a single SNMP packet because even though it is quite slow it happens too fast for debugging. Anyway after few tries it looks like packet is sent relatively slow, response however is immediate. That makes sense in my opinion.

Comment: Maybe the slow query tries to do DNS lookup first and then the packet is send?